# Mapping a 0+ association to a entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I'm using Entity Framework 4.1, and I want to map the following.

```
Car 
- Car_ID
- Name
- Created


Part
- Part_ID
- Car_ID
- Name
- Created
```

So a 'Car' can have 0 or more parts.  And a part has to be associated with a Car.

```
public class Car
{
  [Key]
  [Column("Car_Id")]
   public int Id {get;set;}

   ..
   ..

   public ICollection<Parts> Parts { get; set; } 
}


public class Part
{
  [Key]
  [Column("Part_Id")]
   public int Id {get;set;}

   ..
   ..

   public Car Car { get; set; } 
}
```

My context looks like:

```
public class MyContext :  DbContext
{
 protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
 {
     modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new CarConfiguration());
     modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new PartConfiguration());
 }

}




public class CarConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Car>
{
      public DealerDemoEnrollmentConfiguration()
      {
          this.ToTable("Cars", SchemaName);
          this.HasKey(x => x.Id);
          this.HasMany(x => x.Parts);
      }
}

public class PartConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Part>
{
      public DealerDemoEnrollmentConfiguration()
      {
          this.ToTable("Parts", SchemaName);
          this.HasKey(x => x.Id);
          this.HasRequired(x => x.Car);
      }
}
```

1. I want the Car to be the 'master' entity, so if I want to add a part, I have to do:

   car.Add(part);
2. Will the parts be lazily loaded by default or everytime I load a car, it will load all the parts?  I want it to be lazily loaded by default unless I explicily want all the parts.
3. For learning purposes, what if I didn't want #1, i.e. I wanted just to be able to do:

   part.Car = car
   // save part
   i.e save a part w/o

Comment: you don't need to share parts between cars?

Comment: no not all, they will be all unique to the car.